# QT Signal and Slot between windows

Tags: qt

I want to connect to windows in QT.

I know how to connect two widgets in same window.

`using QObject::connect()` in `ui_a.h`;

But now, I have two windows.

Six files.

For example:

`ui_a.h`(Window A)

`a.h`   `a.cpp` (`Widget` in window A)

`ui_b.h`(Window B)

`b.h`   `b.cpp` (`Widget` in window B)

How to connect two widget which are in different windows?

Thank you.

Comment: when you say two windows do you mean a parent and a child window or two independent windows?

Answer (score 2):

Do the two windows know about each other or are they completly independent? I mean is maybe Window A created by Window B or vice versa? But even if they are independent I assume you have a top parent-object wich creates the two windows right? If so, you should get access to the two widgets in this top parent object. There you can connect them:

`QObject::connect(A->getWidgetInA(), SIGNAL(mySignal()), B->getWidgetInB(), SLOT(mySlot()));`

`getWidgetInA(), getWidgetInB()` just return the pointer to your widgets in Window A and B.

For example in your class Window A: This is how `getWidgetInA()` would look like.

```
#include "a.h"

class WindowA: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:

        WindowA();
        ~WindowA();

     a* getWidgetInA()
     {
         return widget_a;
     }

     private:

        a *widget_a; //in WindowA.cpp you have then widget_a = new a;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand getWidgetInA(). How to return the pointer?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a minimal example for the method getWidgetInA().

Answer (score 2):

You have to find the scope of both window object and connect them there. Perhaps connecting them from `main.cpp` would make it easier. For example,

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
A a;
B b;
QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(someSingal()), &b, SLOT(someSlot()));
QObject::connect(&b, SIGNAL(anotherSingal()), &a, SLOT(anotherSlot()));
a.show();
b.show();
return a.exec();
```

Comment: Hi, I have problem now. In B, I have two widget. How can I connect one of them? Thank you

Comment: Create signal and slots in the widgets of B and connect them from the constructor of B.

Comment: I didn't get it. I've create signal ans slots. What do you mean connect them from the constructor of B?