# How to set text for other window in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have one dialog window and when I click on the button "Ok" it opens another empty window with some empty labels. How can I set text (roots of quadratic equation) for this empty labels?

```
if(!ui->lineEdit->text().isEmpty() && !ui->lineEdit_2->text().isEmpty()
        && !ui->lineEdit_3->text().isEmpty()){
    float x1, x2;
    polynom.setA(ui->lineEdit->text().toDouble());
    polynom.setB(ui->lineEdit_2->text().toDouble());
    polynom.setC(ui->lineEdit_3->text().toDouble());
    polynom.roots(x1, x2);
    Result resultWindow;
    resultWindow.setModal(true);
    resultWindow.exec();
} else{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Error", "Some polynom fields are empty!");
}
```

I want to show roots of quadratic equation in new window.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30249979/5583153) can help you get an idea.

Comment: @Nacho this is not exactly that, what I need. Maybe you can tell me, how can I set some value to label_2, that is placed in other window? This will solve my problem. 
I'll be thankful if you will show some code, that for example takes some input from user and after click show this text in other window, or something same

Comment: Try to do some of the work yourself: in the `Result` class create your labels, and create a function that takes 2 arguments and places them as text in the labels. After that, you can use the `connect` from the link showed by Nacho. If you add that part - even if wrong - we will be happy to help.

Comment: @Thalia sorry, I actually don't understand, how to do it, C++ is now that language, that I'm interested in, just have to do some project for university. If I'm trying to create a function 
class Result : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Result(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void setValueForLabels(QString a, QString b){
        
    }

    ~Result();

private:
    Ui::Result *ui;
};
I can't use ui->label_2->SetText();

Comment: http://thisthread.blogspot.com/2010/06/qdialog-subclass.html this will halp you create a dialog